# Can we apply python decorator at function invoke?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Say for example I have a function

```
def A(): pass
```

I call this function from two different places

```
def B():
    #some code
    A()
    #some code

def C():
    #some code
    A()
    #some code
```

Decorators as we know, in layman language is something like a hook which lets you perform a set of operation before and after the function call. We apply decorators on function definition using `@`.

My requirement here is like I don't want the decorator to be applied every time the function is called. Like in the above example if I apply decorator on function `A`. It would be applied in both invokes. Can we use `@` at the invoke of the function `A`?

Something like,

```
def A(): pass

def B():
    #some code
    A()
    #some code

def C():
    #some code
    @decorator
    A()
    #some code
```

This way I don't have to worry about merging my code after every release of particular opensource project.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay.. I'll change it accordingly

Comment: No need, already done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A decorator is just syntactic sugar, where the outcome of the `@expression` is called and the return value is used to replace the decorated object.

If you only need to have a decorated function in one location you can do `decorator(A)()` to have it return a decorated version just to be used in `C` and call that decorated object on the spot.

Better yet, store that decorated version for C to use so you don't keep decorating it each time:

```
A_decorated = decorator(A)

def C():
    # some code
    A_decorated()
    # some code
```

Comment: In this we are not applying decorator on function A.. But we have created a new decorated function which just calls function A. I wanted to know if we can decorate method A while invoking.

Comment: @Nilesh no, you *are* applying the decorator. A decorator is just a function that takes a function argument and returns a function - the `@` syntax is merely for convenience. Why would you *want* to re-decorate `A` every time it's called?

Comment: @Nilesh: this is doing the *exact same thing* as what using the `@decorator` syntax does. There is nothing magical about decorators, it is *just* syntactic sugar.

Comment: I guess then this should suffice my requirement. Thanks